# Modular interpretation of Ramanujan theta operator?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

I'm a beginner to the theory of modular forms trying to understand a certain construction from the point of view of elliptic curves. Let $f(q) = \sum  a_n q^n$ be a formal power series. Define $\theta f  = q f'(q) = \sum n a_nq^n$. If $f(q)$ is the $q$-expansion of a modular form, it is not true that $\theta f$ is a modular form. However, it is "almost" a modular form: over the complex numbers, it preserves the ring obtained by adding the weight two Eisenstein series $E_2$ to the ring of modular forms $\mathbb{C}[E_4, E_6]$.

If one works $p$-adically, then $E_2$ is the $q$-expansion of a 
weight two $p$-adic modular form (as I learned from Serre's [article](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/courses/gs/Serre.pdf%E2%80%8E) "Formes modulaires et fonctions zeta $p$-adiques"), and in fact, by Theorem 5, sec. 2 of the paper, $\theta$ becomes an operator carrying $p$-adic modular forms of weight $k$ to $p$-adic modular forms of weight $k+2$.

The ring of all $p$-adic modular forms has an interpretation of Katz as functions on the following moduli problem: given a $p$-adically complete ring $R$, consider the collection of all elliptic curves over $R$ together with an isomorphism of their formal group with $\widehat{\mathbb{G_m}}$. 
(There is an action of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ on this moduli problem, and the decomposition of functions on it into characters of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is the weight decomposition of $p$-adic modular forms.) 
Is there a way to interpret $\theta$ in terms of this moduli problem?

Comment: Take a look at the appendices to Katz's "p-adic properties of modular schemes and modular forms" (in one of the Antwerps), especially A1 and A2.  $\theta$ shows up in calculating things like the "Gauss-Manin connection" on $H^1$-de Rham of curves.

Comment: $\theta$ is certainly a vector field on $Spec Z[[q]]$, and corresponds to $d/d\tau$ on the upper-half plane, but I would guess it does not extend over the moduli stack.

Comment: Appendix 2 suggests to me that $\theta$ is modular on the stack of lifts of ordinary curves, though.

Comment: @Charles: thanks! I hadn't seen this part of Katz's article, and will take a look.